# Command for setting permissions on Windows mounted volume

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, permissions, mount

We have several large storage servers running Windows Server 2008 R2. Due to program limitations each server has several disk that had to be broken up into 1TB volumes. These volumes are all mount points on the lettered volume for the disk. The problem that I am facing is changing the permissions on the mount points. Unfortunately, using commands like icacls and get/set-acl only affect the permissions of the folder on the lettered drive and not on the mounted volume. This results in the folders on mounted volume not inheriting the permissions set using icacls or get/set-acls. How can I script setting the psermissions on the mount point so that subfolders inherit the required permissions?[Example of the disconnect in permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2gNh.jpg)

Update:

I thought that I tried icacls as shown below, but I found out that I didn't try it. I was able to get the permissions I was expecting. What I am still trying to find is a PowerShell way to edit permissions using the Volume{GUID} path.

icacls "\?\Volume{GUID}"

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code successfully in PowerShell to set permissions on a mounted volume which are also correctly inherited by its sub-directories and files:

```
mountvol "C:\path-to-mounted-volume" /L | ForEach-Object {
  $volume=$_.Trim()
  ICACLS $volume /grant:r "DOMAIN\GROUP:(OI)(CI)M"
  ICACLS $volume /grant:r "DOMAIN\USER:(OI)(CI)F"
}
```